# Can the Google Directions API do turn by turn directions on android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-directions-api

I'm trying to develop an app that can give you turn by turn directions from a starting point, to multiple stops along the way, and ultimately to a final destination. Can this be done with the directions API? I know it can give me a route, but can it give me turn by turn directions without me having to create my own turn by turn system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just talked to a Google Maps API rep. The short answer is yes, the API does provide turn by turn functionality.